# Weibo login in selenium in python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, weibo

I'm doing weibo login in selenium, but I can't handle window popup.
This is my code. What is problem?

```
from selenium import webdriver

username = 'your id'
password = 'your password'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://overseas.weibo.com/")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

handles = driver.window_handles


driver.find_elements_by_link_text('登入微博')[0].click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.switch_to_alert()
driver.find_element_by_name('memberid').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_name('passwd').send_keys(password)
driver.find_elements_by_link_text('登入')[0].click()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:/python34/weibo_login.py", line 35, in 
>       driver.find_element_by_name('memberid').send_keys(username)
>     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 362, in find_element_by_name
>       return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
>     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 744, in find_element
>       {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
>     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 233, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"memberid"}
>   Stacktrace:
>       at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///C:/Users/hena/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpwk788t0k/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
>       at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///C:/Users/hena/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpwk788t0k/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:625)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually opened login form is inside an `iframe`. It's not an `alert`. You need to switch this particular `iframe` first before find element and `sendKeys` as below :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

username = 'your id'
password = 'your password'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://overseas.weibo.com/")

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

link = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "登入微博")))
link.click()   

frame = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "cboxIframe")))
driver.switch_to_frame(frame)

user = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "memberid")))
user.send_keys(username)

passwd = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "passwd")))
passwd.send_keys(password)

button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "login")))
button.click()
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: @오은아은아 you welcome... glad to help you... I'm just trying to provide you the best way for locating element...:)

Comment: yeah your code is best .but it's easy to my code understand to me ^^

Comment: @오은아은아 hahahha ok.. if you want your code as it is you just replace `driver.switch_to_alert()` to `driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_class_name('cboxIframe'))`..it will also work well...:)

Comment: @오은아은아 but i'm suggesting you use my provided code for best practice...:)